# show hide menu on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

so i have this html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>categ 1</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a>subcateg 1</a><li>
           <li><a>subcateg 1</a><li>
        </ul>
    <li><a>categ2</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a>subcateg 2</a><li>
           <li><a>subcateg 3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a>sub sub categ 3</a><li>
                <li><a>sub sub categ 3</a><li>
              </ul>
           <li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

etc.

and js is http://jsfiddle.net/fMm3A/ - click on red area(there needs to be an image, but for this test i just put a red bg)

i would like to open submenus but don't close the parent branch, but when i open other branch the other ones will close

thank you

Comment: Why don't you try for CSS?

Comment: because it's on click, not hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTMl list you posted here is full of errors (you are not closing the lists (''), you have forgotten some tags... But well, after correcting them:

What about this: http://jsfiddle.net/wpWmM/2/

Here's with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/fMm3A/12/

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).closest('.parent').siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
});
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    display:none;
}
ul.visible{
    display: block;
}
```

In the HTMl you would need to add the class `parent` to the main elements and the class `visible` to the main `ul`. You can see it [on my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wpWmM/2/)

Comment: when i open the second category, i want the first one to close. and if i open a sub sub category, i don;t want that the category to close

Comment: @Vlad I've updated my answer. And here's with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/fMm3A/12/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS also:

e.g.

change your css

> ```
> #leftNav > li > ul { list-style:none; }
> ```

to this:

> ```
> #leftNav > li > ul { list-style:none; display:none;}
> #leftNav > li:hover > ul { list-style:none; display:block;}
> ```

**Note**: This is only for Top level. For next level you need to do the
same thing.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ktzav/)

Comment: The question was about how to do it with a `click` event, not `hover`.

Comment: @putvande ok boss :).I am just giving the suggestion that he can do this without any javascript code. It is possible it CSS and permormance wise is good. Thanks for down voting.

Answer (score 0):

Apply some class to each of the menu link e.g `menuLink`

Hide all the parent `ul` by using a class e.g `hide`

Than try this

```
$('.menuLink').click(function(){
           $(".hide").not($(this).next()).hide();
            $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        });
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fMm3A/11/)